# Type inference not working on reference parameter of React.forwardRef()

Tags: reactjs, typescript, intellij-idea, tslint

I am trying to utilize `React.forwardRef()` and I'm scratching my head over the following issue:

[image]

It appears that IntelliJ is able to correctly interfer the type of the reference, which is `FilterRef` in this case.

However, I am unable to access the current value `ref.current` without a compilation error stating that this would not exist.

Printing it out at runtime, of course, confirms that `current` is an existing attribute.

Not sure what causes this issue.

#### Code

I am creating a reference which I want to share with a `Filter` component and a context-provider:

```js
const filterRef = useRef<FilterElement>({ filters, setFilters: onSetFilters });

console.log('filterRef', filterRef);

return (
  <>
    <Filter ref={filterRef} />
    <FilterContext.Provider value={{ ref: filterRef }}>
      <Outlet />
    </FilterContext.Provider>
  </>
);
```

However, `current` is always `null`:

```js
export const Filter = React.forwardRef<FilterElement, FilterProps>((props, ref) => {
  const filterRef = useRef<FilterElement>(null);
  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => filterRef.current!, []);

  console.log('filter', filterRef, ref);
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit 2**

In order to have a separate state being managed by `Filter` itself, the following can be done as well:

```js
export const Filter = React.forwardRef<FilterElement | undefined, FilterProps>((props, ref) => {
  const [filters, setFilters] = useState<FilterItem[]>([]);
  const refInstance: FilterElement = useMemo(() => {
    return {
      filters,
      setFilters,
    };
  }, [filters]);
  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => refInstance, [refInstance]);
  // ...
}
```

**Edit:**

Based on the updated code, I think you don't need the `ref` at all, as you can just pass `filters` and `setFilters` to both the `Filter` component as well as the `FilterContext` provider:

```
<Filter filters={ filters } setFilters={ onSetFilters } />
<FilterContext.Provider value={{ filters, setFilters: onSetFilters }}>
  <Outlet />
</FilterContext.Provider>
```

In any case, if you want to do that, you don't need to use `forwardRef`, just name your prop something else and type it as `RefObject`:

```
const App = () => {
  const filterRef = useRef<FilterElement>({ filters, setFilters: onSetFilters });

  return (
    <>
      <Filter filterRef={filterRef} />
      <FilterContext.Provider value={{ ref: filterRef }}>
        <Outlet />
      </FilterContext.Provider>
    </>
  );
} 

export interface FilterProps {
  filterRef: RefObject<FilterElement>;
}

export const Filter: React.FC<FilterProps> = ({ filterRef }) => {
  console.log('filter', filterRef);

  // ...
}
```

The answer below with `useImperativeHandler` would be used if you want to use a `ref` inside the `Filter` component, but also want to expose that same `ref` to the parent.

**Original answer:**

Refs can either be an object with a `current` property, like the ones returned by [`useRef`](https://react.dev/reference/react/useRef) or a [`ref` callback function](https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/components/common#ref-callback), so the compiler is right.

You should create a new `ref` in your `Filter` component and use [`useImperativeHandle`](https://react.dev/reference/react/useImperativeHandle) to sync it with the forwarded one:

```
export const Filter = forwardRef<FilterRef, FilterProps>((props, ref) => {
  const filterRef = useRef(null);

  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => filterRef.current!, []);

  ...
});
```

Comment: I'm getting "_ESLint: Forbidden non-null assertion._" inside `useImperativeHandle()`. Any way to get rid of this warning? :/

Comment: Just tried i t- I'm not able to make this work. See my updated question.

Comment: @StefanFalk Ok, see the updated answer.

Comment: I've now understood that I misunderstood what `useImperativeHandle()` does. Since I want `Filter` to have its own state, `useImperativeHandle` was the right choice but instead of returning `filterRef.current!` I am now returning `{ filters, setFilters }` (calling `useState()` insider the `Filter` component) in order to have easy access to individual references to a `FilterElement`.

Comment: I've added my solution to your answer - hope that's alright. Feel free to edit in case you want to address something :) Thanks for your help!